# Eliminar registros en un SQL

Tags: sql

Estoy haciendo un análisis de facturas para un cliente, y en su base de datos tengo él:

> ID, nombre y demás campos importantes en una factura;

Además, tengo los `productos facturados`, ¿el problema? En mi SQL tengo una línea para cada producto, tengo una columna para el total `(total facturado)` el cual es uno solo (obviamente), pero se repite en cada línea del producto y no sé cómo eliminarlo para poder sacar el valor ticket promedio porque ese total se repite, por lo que los números no son correctos. ¿Me pueden ayudar?

En la imagen se muestra

> cantidad, precio de venta, monto total (por producto) y el total de la
> factura,

El cual es el que se repite y lo necesito una sola vez. O bien, necesito una fórmula agregada para sumar todos los montos totales `(penúltima columna)` si por número de factura `(el cual es único)`. Muchas gracias de antemano

:)[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`````
SELECT
         i."Invoice ID" as 'Factura ID',
         i."Invoice Number" as 'Número de Factura',
         i."Invoice Date" as 'Fecha de Factura',
         i."Customer ID" as 'Cliente ID',
         c."Customer Name" as 'Cliente',
         ii."Product ID" as 'Producto ID',
         ii."Item Name" as 'Producto',
         ii."Description" as 'Descripción del Producto',
         ii."Quantity" as 'Cantidad Vendida',
         ii."Item Price" as 'Precio de Venta',
         ii."Total (BCY)" as 'Monto Total',
         i."Total (BCY)" as 'Total factura',
         p."Purchase Price" as 'Precio de Compra'
FROM  "Invoices" i
JOIN "Customers" c ON i."Customer ID"  = c."Customer ID" 
JOIN "Invoice Items" ii ON i."Invoice ID"  = ii."Invoice ID" 
LEFT JOIN "Items" p ON ii."Product ID"  = p."Item ID"  
WHERE    c."Customer Name"  = 'San Martin Distributing Inc.'````
`````

Comment: Mi recomendación es crear una nueva tabla con el total de la factura y los campos únicos que contenga la misma, los típicos de cliente, etc, desvinculándolos de cada artículo del detalle de la factura. Por lo tanto esa columna sobra en esa tabla. Otra forma sería no tener esa nueva tabla de facturas y simplemente realizar el cálculo del total cada vez que sea necesario contando los monto totales por artículo que sean de la misma factura, ya sea por SQL o bien por el lenguaje de programación que estés usando para montar esa salida.

Comment: De hecho, si me apuras mucho, tambien sobra la del monto total por producto, pues lo puedes calcular con la cantidad vendida*precio venta cuando lo necesites.

Comment: Muchas gracias. De hecho tengo la tabla solo de facturas, pero esa tabla no tiene los productos, y necesito poder filtrar por productos, entonces no puedo utilizar esa solución que me dices :( Mueroooo

Comment: SQL te permite unir tablas en las consultas de diversos modos. Revisa bien como se hacen consultas [JOIN](https://diego.com.es/principales-tipos-de-joins-en-sql) entre tablas para sacar todos esos datos de una tacada o bien en un par de consultas para que no se repitan los campos totales.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Tenes un problema de diseño... las columnas calculadas, salvo que sea un datawarehouse, no deberian estar. Y para sacar los totales por factura, agrupas por el id de factura!

Comment: ok, muchas gracias, soy nueva en esto. No tiene ninguna columna calculada, ese dato viene (total valor de productos), intente agrupar por el ID de Factura pero me indica mal uso del Group BY. Uso Zoho Analytics. Conseguí una manera y es otra tabla con SELECT DISTINCT para que me traiga solo el ID de Factura y el total :)

Comment: ¿Lo que buscas es obtener el promedio por factura? te sugiero que agregues el código de esta consulta editando tu pregunta, va a ser más fácil darte una respuesta.

Comment: Si, necesito el promedio o el total facturado (mejor). Ok. Agrego el código.

Comment: Total o Promedio, puedes hacer algo así `SELECT  SUM(i."Total (BCY)") as 'Total', AVG(i."Total (BCY)") as 'Promedio'  FROM  "Invoices" i WHERE  c."Customer Name"  = 'San Martin Distributing Inc.'`, estoy asumiendo SQL Server, pero me parece que se trata de otro motor.